# Finding an unknown using quadratic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, triangles, area

[Problem http://puu.sh/rHIrw.png](http://puu.sh/rHIrw.png)

> $PQRS$ is a rectangle. $MS=NP=x$ units and the area of the triangle $MNQ$ is 38 units squared. Find the possible values of $x$.

The way I did it was substituting $MR$ as $12-x$ and $SN$ as $9-x$ and used that information to apply the pythagorean theorem to figure out the sides $MQ$ and $MN$. But I'm not sure if that'll help me. I know that certain triangles in a quadrilateral are right triangles but I don't know what tools should I use to prove that. In the end, all of my calculations are really just using the pythagorean theorem. My intuition is telling me that $MQ$ is the height but I don't trust myself unless I do a proof about it. Thus, I can't figure out a way on how to use the information regarding the area of the triangle $MNQ$.

Comment: There is no need to find the lengths of the sides of MNQ. Just setting up an equation relating the areas will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to this problem is to compute the area of $\triangle MNQ$ indirectly by *subtracting* the other regions of rectangle $PQRS$. These other regions are $\triangle NPQ$, $\triangle MSN$ and $\triangle QRM$, which have areas $\frac12(12x),\frac12x(9-x),\frac12(9(12-x))$ respectively. The area of the whole rectangle is $9\cdot12=108$, so the area of $\triangle MNQ$ is
$$108-\frac12(12x)-\frac12x(9-x)-\frac12(9(12-x))$$
$$=108-6x-\frac12(x(9-x)+9(12-x))$$
$$=108-6x-\frac12(9x-x^2+108-9x)$$
$$=108-6x+\frac12x^2-54$$
$$=\frac12x^2-6x+54$$
Since the area is equal to 38:
$$\frac12x^2-6x+54=38$$
$$\frac12x^2-6x+16=0$$
$$x^2-12x+32=0$$
$$(x-4)(x-8)=0$$
$$x=4\text{ or }x=8$$
Since both these numbers are less than 9, they are the possible values for $x$.